# Get Color Data of HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to get the percentage of a color in a HTML5 Canvas.
I have a Canvas, where you can draw lines in three colors with the mouse or clean it with a white line.

Now I want to get the percentage of a color in the whole canvas.

I try that:

```
var c = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

var allPixel=0;
for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
 allPixel+=1;
  if(imgData.data[i+2]==255)
    blue+=1;
  else if (imgData.data[i]==255)
    red+=1;
  else if (imgData.data[i+1]==green)
    green +=1;
}
```

But this seems to be wrong. The values are strange and always go very high. How can I get the right values of the whole canvas and a color to calculate the percentage.

Can you help me?

And how is it possible with another color instead of the full RGB colors , for example Yellow or white?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the percentage of a color" ? What you try to achieve is unclear.

Comment: Hey, for example: I draw with blue on my white canvas. Then I want to know, how many Pixels of my canvas are blue. And then calculate the percent value (e.g. 20% of the canvas is blue)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color White is the mix of red green and blue channel. Looking for the value of a single channel won't give you much...

Answer (score 0):

White is equal to `rgb(255,255,255)` so you might be counting that as blue. Also it might be easier to loop through each x and y and get the data, where this code gets the data at exactly one pixel.

```
var col = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1).data
var red = col[0];
var green = col[1]; 
var blue = col[2];
// increment values
```